# Setting tasks to `SCHED_FIFO`: is this dangerous? Is this efficient?

Tags: linux, operating-system, scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling

I have some CPU-intensive tasks that I want to run on a server, and I want to make sure it gets highest priority by setting its scheduler to `SCHED_FIFO` (since the realtime scheduling class has higher priority than the CFS scheduling class).

I have 8-cores.
I want to split up the work into 7 processes (leave 1 runqueue for daemons), and schedule them all as `SCHED_FIFO`.

Is this ever a dangerous idea? Will this necessarily improve my performance? Is there a better way to approach the problem?

I am not worried about starving other tasks, and each process only runs on a single thread.

Comment: Assuming that each process has only one thread, and that you seem to have approx. as many processes as cores, does the scheduling policy matter much?

Comment: @MartinJames Maybe it's negligible, but being on the default Linux scheduler (CFS) will cause it to context switch every time quantum for some other process that may be on the run queue, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: @gust how did this go? I'm looking for the same thing, without sorting to a RTOS. I'd prefer RT PATCH is merged in to the main Linux kernel.

Comment: @intrigued_66 Never ended up implementing this, sorry.